# Python embed into C++

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api

I have python codes ebmedded into C++.
Do I need to `release memory(Py_XDECREF)` PyObject* pValue and PyObject *pArgs?

When I do Py_XDECREF(pArgs) and Py_XDECREF(pValue) I have Segmentation Fault (Core dumped).
I think python side is still using those variables and c++ try to release memory.
What is the best practice for this issue?

```
for(int i=0; i < 100: i++){
        .......do sth.......
    if (pModule != NULL) {
            std::string st = jps.updateZone(worldx_y, lenVect);                          
            PyObject* pValue = PyBytes_FromString(st.c_str());
            if (pFunc_insert && PyCallable_Check(pFunc_insert)) {
                PyObject *pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
                PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs, 0, pValue);
                PyObject_CallObject(pFunc_insert, pArgs); 
                Py_XDECREF(pArgs);                               
            } 
            Py_XDECREF(pValue);              
    }
        ......do sth.......

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PyTuple_SetItem` [steals](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_SetItem) a reference to the item. You **don't** need to decref the item, because you no longer own a reference to it. You **do** need to decref the tuple.

If you still get segfaults after that, you have some other bug.

Comment: You meant I do not  need for both pValue and pARGs?